# How to get XMLHttpResponse from a java class to JS in JSP and parse it

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2, tiles

When a user clicks on the hyperlink, the controls goes to the scipt and from there to a action file.

showregistrations.jsp

```
<s:iterator value="list">
<table
<td><a href="#" class="userName" id='<s:property value="userName"/>'><s:property value="userName"/></a></td>
</table>
</s:iterator>
```

JavaScript(This is inside the `showregistrations.jsp`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.userName').click(function(){
        var userName= $(this).attr('id');
        var ajax    = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST","getUserDetails",false);
        ajax.send(userName);
    });
</script>
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="getUserDetails" class="com.ActionClasses.GetUserDetailsAction">
    <result name="success"  type="tiles">showUserDetails</result>
</action>
```

*GetUserDetailsAction.java* is returning "success".

tiles.xml

```
<definition name="showUserDetails" extends="home">
    <put-attribute name="Title" value="User Details"/>
    <put-attribute name="Menu"  value="/mainMenu.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="Body"  value="/showUserDetails.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

But this is not redirectering to `showUserDetails.jsp`

EDIT:

I found that the control comes to JS from where I called the action. Can some one tell me how can I get the response from the class `GetUserDetailsAction` to the `showregistrations.jsp`(from here I am calling that action file).

Here is my GetUserDetailsAction.java

```
HttpServletRequest req=null;

GetUserDetailsBean getUserDetailsBean = new GetUserDetailsBean();
private String userName;


public String execute(){
    System.out.println("came to getuserdetailsaction");
    try {
        InputStream is = req.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[32];
        int dataLength=0;

        while( dataLength >= 0 ) {
            dataLength = is.read(dataBuffer);
            if( dataLength >= 0 ) os.write(dataBuffer, 0, dataLength);
        }

        userName = new String(os.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GetUserDetailsDao getUserDetailsDao = new GetUserDetailsDao();
    getUserDetailsDao.getDetails(userName, getUserDetailsBean);
    //getUserDetailsDao.getDetails is filling the details into getUserDetailsBean. How can I send this bean to the JS and print it there.
    System.out.println("returning success from getuserdetails action");
    return SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Why you are using ajax if you want to redirect to that page?

Comment: To know on which __userName__ does the end user clicked.

Comment: You don't need ajax to get *on which userName does the end user clicked*. Read again very carefully Andrea Ligios answer to your previous post.

Comment: Andrea told to perform the AJAX call to the action that loads the student's details

Comment: @AleksandrM. That's okay. i have the same issue in othre places too. Can you tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For your first part of the question i.e., for redirectering to another jsp you can use `window.location="actionName.action";` as you using struts and tiles. other wise you can directly write `window.location=something.jsp`

I don't know how to send response from java class to jsp.